# How to write correct query for Haystack + Whoosh in Django

Tags: python, django, django-haystack, whoosh

I have model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250)
    text = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And file search_indexes.py:

```
from haystack import indexes
from haystack import site
from models import Article

class ArticleIndex(indexes.SearchIndex):
    text_q = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    text = indexes.CharField(model_attr='text')

    # what I must add here ???

site.register(Article, ArticleIndex)
```

When I execute query it can find only than words which I have in TITLE field.
When I use word combination from TEXT field I got "No results found"

What I must add for executing queries with words from TEXT field?

Answer (score 0):

The query only looks in the field marked `document=True` (the other fields can only be used for later filtering)

The [documentation](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v1.2.7/tutorial.html#handling-data) recommends naming that 'text'.

As you have `use_template=True` you should have a template that specifies what object fields are in the document.

e.g. templates/search/indexes/main/article_text.txt could contain

```
{{ object.title }}
{{ object.text }}
```